# my wepApi giving error when I try open my psd html file

Tags: html, adobe, photoshop, webapi

I Have wepApi project but I want to use it with adobe photoshop.So I design to web site with adobe and after I convert to html file.But When I try to open it with localhost it's giving me error.But it's working on live server.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFBsH.png)

I never used before abode but I have to for one project.So maybe someone know what is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several potential causes for this problem. Here are a few potential answers:

1. Ensure that your local machine is running a web server. The HTML file won't be able to connect to your API without a web server.
2. Ensure that the URL you are using to access the HTML file is correct. The format should be "http://localhost/path/to/file.html."
3. Make sure your web server is operational and properly configured if you use one.
4. Make sure your HTML file is free of syntax mistakes. To check for issues, you can use a tool like the W3C Markup Validation Service.

I hope this is useful.